# In which scenarios would you initialize a value type with a new keyword?

Tags: c#, initialization, value-type

My question is about using `new` for a value type (`int`, `bool`,...)

```
int i = new int();
```

in this case `i` is initialized with a value zero.

I have read that it's not a good thing to use `new` with the value types and does not, however, dynamically allocate memory(just on stack).
So the questions is why the C# Compiler makers have let us to do so, in which situation this method comes handy?

Comment: I edited your answer and removed c# from tag - please read: [Should questions include tags in their title](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have read that it's not a good thing to use new with the value types and does not, however, dynamically allocate memory(just on stack). So the questions is why the C# Compiler makers have let us to do so, in which situation this method comes handy?

There is at least one reason for this:

```
void MyFunc<T>() where T : new()
{
    T someValue = new T();
    // probably other code here :-)
}
```

call it with

```
MyFunc<int>();
```

With generics you must be able to use the `new()`. if some value types didn't have the `new()` then it would be impossible to write code like that.

Note that for `int`, `long`, ... and nearly all the other primitive value types (except `bool`, and for `bool` there is the `new bool() == false`) you can use numeric literals to initialize them (0, 1, ...), but for other value types you can't. You have to use static values (that are then built in some other ways) or the new operator. For example `DateTime` :-)

You can't write:

```
DateTime dt = 0;
```

You have to write:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.MinValue; // Where DateTime.MinValue is probably defined as new DateTime()
```

or

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime();
```

or

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2015, 02, 28);
```

or (as written by Henk Holterman)

```
DateTime dt = default(DateTime);
```

(note that you can even write `int x = default(int)` :-) )

Comment: For completeness, you can also write  `DateTime dt = default(DateTime);`

Comment: @HenkHolterman yep... I had thought about the `default` operator while writing the generic example, because the `default(T)` is a classical use of that operator (and for value types `new T() == default(T)`, but then I decided it was better to "non mettere troppa carne al fuoco" (don't put too much meat on the fire)

Answer (score 0):

Value type are also object. This is a call to the default constructor of the corresponding value type. Here is MSDN note about it.

> The new operator is also used to invoke the default constructor for value types. For example:
>   int i = new int();
>   In the preceding statement, i is initialized to 0, which is the default value for the type int. The statement has the same effect as the following:
>   int i = 0;

and ...

> **Value-type objects such as structs are created on the stack**, while reference-type objects such as classes are created on the heap. Both types of objects are destroyed automatically, but objects based on value types are destroyed when they go out of scope, whereas objects based on reference types are destroyed at an unspecified time after the last reference to them is removed.

More [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fa0ab757.aspx)

Comment: It is absolutely terrible that even MSDN writes that "Value-type objects such as structs are created on the stack". An int inside a class "lives" inside the heap.

Comment: before asking the question I have read that article , but my question is about the meaning of it , like can you write a code where using new for var type comes handy? or solve a problem ? I want to understand the idea behind letting it .

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing 'bad' in using new with primitive types like int. Since they all derive from object they have a default parameterless constructor which is called when you do int i = new int(). Initializing an int like this assigns it a default value of 0, which is the same as writing int i = 0;

I don't think anyone but the developers of C# can answer why they left this construct, but if I were you I wouldn't worry too much about int i = new int() and would keep to the good old int i = 0 (or whatever value you like).

UPD:

J Richter wrote a good book about CLR called 'CLR via C#'. It covers a lot of questions like this one.